# .NET Core 2 with EF Core different contexts with different schemas in same DB(SQL Server)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I would like to have my tables in a C# ASP.NET Core 2 application in two separate schemas.  I have created two separate DB contexts and different connection strings in `appsettings.json`.

appsettings.json

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=db;Database=DB;User=u;Password=pwd;",
"InventoryCon": "Server=db;Database=DB;User=u;Password=pwd;"
```

startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<CustomerDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddDbContext<InventoryDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("InventoryCon")));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I am specifying default schema in each of the dbContextClasses:
Inventory:

```
...protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("inventory");
}
```

Customer:

```
...protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("customer");
}
```

In Program I am trying to seed both:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<CustomerDbContext>();
            DbInitializer.Initialize(context);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding Customer database.");
        }

        try
        {
            var contexti = services.GetRequiredService<InventoryDbContext>();
            DbInitializer.InitInventory(contexti);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding Inventory database.");
        }
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

The above works fine if the connections strings are to different databases so I am guessing it has an issue with two connection strings to the same DB.  Ideally I could separate out these tables into separate schemas so I can better control access for queries.

Any ideas on how I can separate my tables into separate schemas?

EDIT:  Adding ERROR:

> info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'InventoryDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure:Information: Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'InventoryDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
>   info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (32ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (32ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
>   'dotnet.exe"' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.4\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'dotnet.exe"' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.4\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
>         Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SELECT CASE
>             WHEN EXISTS (
>                 SELECT 1
>                 FROM [inventory].[DUA] AS [d])
>             THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
>         END
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'inventory.DUA'.

I noticed the following in the logs when it creates the schema for customer, which never happens for inventory:
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'customer') IS NULL EXEC(N'CREATE SCHEMA [customer];');

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @ajawad987 I added my error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was I was using EF with database.EnsureCreated which only checks if the database is there and if not it creates the DB and the specified schema for that context.  On successive calls it sees the database and does not create the schema.  The explanation and solution is by rowan miller [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4468).

Answer (score 3):

I want to say that its complaining about both contexts writing to the same 'default' migrations history table in the database.

To get around this, you'll need to slightly modify your service configuration so that it specifies different migration tables for each of the contexts you have:

```
services.AddDbContext<CustomerDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(
                    this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.MigrationsHistoryTable("Customer")));

services.AddDbContext<InventoryDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(
                    this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.MigrationsHistoryTable("Inventory")));
```

Edit: Fixed the code snippet.

Comment: ajawad987 Thanks for the response.  The above beginning with the lambda expression will not compile with the error: cannot convert lamda expression to type ServiceLifetime because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Fixed the code snippet. I had extra parenthesis which were causing issues.

Comment: Thanks.  This compiles and runs now however I am getting the same errors.  It won't create that second schema.

Comment: Just curious, if you happened to have added an entity type `DUA` *after* creating an EF migration. If so, you'll need to regenerate the migration so it includes the schema information for the DUA table.

Comment: Thanks for all the information.  This lead me to the reason why it wasn't working.  I was using ensure database created which doesn't create migrations.  If I actually go in and specify to create migrations and use localdb it creates the schemas fine.  I am using docker and it seems ef migrations command can't connect to a docker db.  Thanks again.